# Expansion of function-like macro creates a separate token

Tags: c, macros, c99

I just found out that gcc seems to treat the result of the expansion of a function-like macro as a separate token. Here is a simple example showing the behavior of gcc:

```
#define f() foo
void f()_bar(void);
void f()bar(void);
void f()-bar(void);
```

When I execute `gcc -E -P test.c` (running just the preprocessor), I get the following output:

```
void foo _bar(void);
void foo bar(void);
void foo-bar(void);
```

It seems like, in the first two definitions, gcc inserts space after the expanded macro to ensure it is a separate token. Is that really what is happening here?

Is this mandated by any standard (I couldn't find documentation on the topic)?

I want to make `_bar` part of the same token. Is there any way to do this? I could use the token concatenation operator `##` but it will require several levels of macros (since in the real code f() is more complex). I was wondering if there is a simple (and probably more readable) solution.

Comment: Is google down? Did you not even try to find the C [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3) which is **apparently** the authoritative source to consult.

Comment: @Olaf - I didn't find any explicit statement answering my question in neither C99 nor the link you pointed me to.

Comment: To be fair the behaviour as described in the standard is not entirely obvious. I'm guessing the keyword is that the preprocessor replaces the macro with *tokens*, which means whitespace will be inserted where necessary to actually do so.

Comment: I think: use ## between the elements so they are concatenated into a single token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It seems like, in the first two definitions, gcc inserts space after the expanded macro to ensure it is a separate token. Is that really what is happening here?*

Yes.

*Is this mandated by any standard (I couldn't find documentation on the topic)?*

Yes, although an implementation would be allowed to insert even more than one whitespace to separate the tokens.

`f()_bar`

here you have 4 tokens after lexical analysis (they are actually pre-processor tokens at this stage but let's call them tokens): `f`, `(`, `)` and `_bar`.

The function-like macro replacement semantic (as defined in C11, 6.10.3) has to replace the 3 token `f`, `(`, `)` into a new one `foo`. It is not allowed to work on other tokens and change the last `_bar` token. For this the implementation has to insert at least one  whitespace to preserve `_bar` token. Otherwise the result would have been `foo_bar` which is a single token.

`gcc` preprocessor somewhat [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization) it here:

> Once the input file is broken into tokens, the token boundaries never change, except when the ‘##’ preprocessing operator is used to paste tokens together. See Concatenation. For example,
>
> ```
> #define foo() bar
> foo()baz
>      ==> bar baz
> not
>      ==> barbaz
> ```

In the other case, like `f()-bar`, there 5 tokens: `f`, `(`, `)`, `-` and `bar`. (`-` is a punctuator token in C whereas `_` in `_bar` is simply a character of the identifier token). The implementation does not have to insert token separator  (as whitespace) here as after macro replacement `-bar` are still considered as two separate tokens from C syntax.

`gcc` preprocessor (`cpp`) does not insert whitespace here simply because it does not have to. In `cpp` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Token-Spacing.html), on token spacing it is written (on a different issue):

> However, we would like to keep space insertion to a minimum, both for aesthetic reasons and because it causes problems for people who still try to abuse the preprocessor for things like Fortran source and Makefiles.

I didn't address the solution to your issue in this answer, but I think you have to use operator explicitly specified to concatenate tokens: the `##` token pasting operator.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of (if you can not use the token concatenation operator ##) is using the traditional (pre-standard) C preprocessing:

```
gcc -E -P -traditional-cpp test.c
```

Output:

```
void foo_bar(void);
void foobar(void);
void foo-bar(void);
```

[More info](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html)